# How can I forward Subdomains w/Cloudflare, without Page Rules?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, web, cloudflare

I'm trying to add several subdomain forwards to external URL's, I have moved for domain from GoDaddy to Cloudflare for the purpose of security, speed and safety. Although GoDaddy makes it very easy to set up subdomain fowards, Cloudflare doesn't seem to do so. Is there a way to do subdomain forwards on Cloudflare without using Page Rules, I've searched and can't find a way to do this. Thanks!

e.g. blog.magnaboy.com ----> magnaboysblog.com etc

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by setting as DNS entry for 'blog' as a CNAME to *. Then in the root of the site use .htacess (linux) or web.config (windows) to consolidate the naked domain name.

Here is the web.config example:

```
<!--# CONSOLIDATE DOMAIN NAME -->
<rule name="Point to naked domain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*$)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" pattern="^magnaboy\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://magnaboy.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This will 301 redirect anysubdomain.magnaboy.com to magnaboysblog.com